# Optimal block size in java streams

Tags: java, sockets, stream, io

I have a theoretical question. Let's imagine you have an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`. You nead to copy content from one to the other and you don't know exactly the size of the content you need to transfer. What is the best choice in general of the block size in the `write` method?

Comment: This is known as "premature optimization".  Use a library such as Apache Commons IO and then, if you have performance problems, tune the block size.  The optimal value will depend on what's connected to the input and output streams (a disk file, a pipe, a network connection, etc)

Comment: I usually use 4096 as block size for file access. It's efficient in many cases. Though 4096 is very small block, compared to disk access cost, method invocation cost is ignorable.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is: **it depends.** For a general solution, **stop worrying** about it and just use a library. Common choices:

- [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [`IOUtils#copy()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) or [`copyLarge()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29), or
- [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`ByteStreams#copy()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Answer (score 4):

The default buffer size for BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream is 8 KB and this is typically a good size.

Note: if you are reading a Socket fast enough, you will rarely get more one packet, ~1.5 KB. If you are reading from disk, you typically get whatever size you ask for, however the performance doesn't improve much from 32 KB to 256 KB and is likely to be dependant on the hardware you use.

However I have also found, unless you are benchmarking you rarely see a noticeable difference if you use only 512 bytes as a buffer size (which Inflator/Deflator streams do) i.e. the difference might be 15% or less.

In summary, you are unlikely to notice a difference with buffer sizes between 512 bytes and 32 KB. The latter is likely to be more than enough for most situations.  I tend to use 256 KB as I have a lot of memory and few pre-allocated buffers.